# Appending multi-element to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net

I have a data that look like this:

```
List<Deal> deals = new List<Deal>
{
    new Deal
    {
        DealNo = "S001",
        DealItem = new List<string> { "A001", "A002", "A003" }
    },
    new Deal
    {
        DealNo = "S002",
        DealItem = new List<string> { "T001", "T002" }
    }
};
```

And I want my output to look like this:

```
<Resource>
  <ResourceID>
    <ResourceBody>
      <DealNo>S001</DealNo>
      <ItemList>
        <Item>A001</Item>
        <Item>A002</Item>
        <Item>A003</Item>
      </ItemList>
      <DealNo>S002</DealNo>
      <ItemList>
        <Item>T001</Item>
        <Item>T002</Item>
      </ItemList>
    </ResourceBody>
  </ResourceID>
</Resource>
```

I'm stuck at trying to loop through the ItemList element and adding nodes inside. This is what I have now:

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
// This structure is from other parts of the system, I can't change this
xdoc.LoadXml("<Resource><ResourceID><ResourceBody></ResourceBody></ResourceID></Resource>");

foreach (var deal in deals)
{
    var node = xdoc.CreateNode("element", "DealNo", "");
    node.InnerText = deal.DealNo;
    var singleNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Resource/ResourceID/ResourceBody");
    singleNode.AppendChild(node);

    node = xdoc.CreateElement("ItemList");
    singleNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Resource/ResourceID/ResourceBody");
    singleNode.AppendChild(node);
}
```

How do I loop through all the 'deals' and append through all the ItemList elements?

Constraints: I am forced to work with XmlDocument, it's part of old codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your sample, simply add a new loop to add your deal items:

```
foreach (var deal in deals) {
    var node = xdoc.CreateNode("element", "DealNo", "");
    node.InnerText = deal.DealNo;
    var singleNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Resource/ResourceID/ResourceBody");
    singleNode.AppendChild(node);

    node = xdoc.CreateElement("ItemList");
    singleNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Resource/ResourceID/ResourceBody");

    // Add deal items here...
    foreach (string dealItem in deal.DealItem) {
        var dealItemNode = xdoc.CreateNode("element", "Item", "");
        dealItemNode.InnerText = dealItem;
        node.AppendChild(dealItemNode);
    }

    singleNode.AppendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! My brain kinda got stuck there, I really couldn't think that one out. Thanks again :)

Now to translate this logic into C/AL... (I originally got this problem in Dynamics NAV, I just put C# here because the audience is wider)